# Nginx Ingress - use https for backend based on path

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm configuring ingress to pass requests to backends based on path. Only `service-external` needs to use HTTPS. If I add annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: 'HTTPS'`, ingress will use https for both backends, which is not desired. Is there anyway to use https for selected backends only?

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'true'
  tls:
  - secretName: my-tls
    hosts:
    - myhost.com
  rules:
  - host: myhost.com
    paths:
    - path: /external/
      serviceName: service-external
      servicePort: 443
    - path: /
      serviceName: service-api
```

Comment: The only way to achive this is create another ingress without TLS information, you can do this using the same host. Is it an option for you? If yes, I can post an example as a answer.

Comment: Does that mean allowing `http://myhost.com` as well?

Comment: Yes, you could create another ingress spec with `myhost.com` and the desired path without TLS.

Comment: that is not quite what i want. because then https traffic won't be able to go to http backend right?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, the use of an annotation in an ingress spec will enable this functionality for all paths.

The only way to achieve what you want is create a new ingress spec with the desired path. So you will have 2 ingress for the same `host`, see this example:

I'm configuring ingress to pass requests to backends based on path. Only  `service-external`  needs to use HTTPS. If I add annotation  `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: 'HTTPS'`, ingress will use https for both backends, which is not desired. Is there anyway to use https for selected backends only?

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-https-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol:  "HTTPS"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - myapp.com
      secretName: myapp.com
  rules:
  - host: myapp.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/"
        backend:
          serviceName: my-https-service
          servicePort: 443
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-http-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - myapp.com
      secretName: myapp.com
  rules:
  - host: myapp.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/notsecure"
        backend:
          serviceName: my-http-service
          servicePort: 80
```

The first ingress will redirect every request for `https://myapp.com/` to `my-https-service` and if the request was to `https://myapp.com/notsecure` the request will be redirect to  the service `my-http-service` over HTTP, but for the end user the connection still **HTTPS**.